# How to set the default value for textarea in struts2

Tags: java, struts2, struts

I would like to know how the default value can be set in textarea , the scenario would be after a page refresh , or fail of validation bedore save operation.

```
<s:textarea name="desc" value="" theme="xhtml" required="true" cssClass="text textarea small"/>
```

value="<%= "Default" %>"  , this code is not working out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but IMO this is the same as for any field: the *value* attribute of a [Struts2 tag](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11.1/docs/tag-syntax.html) looks up the respective property in your stack. In the typical scenario, when you type, say, `<s:textarea value="comment" ..>` Struts2 will use the `MyAction.getComment()` and `MyAction.setComment()` to read/write the textarea value. Then, you just have to assign a default value for the attribute in your action -which, BTW, is conceptually the right way.

```
  public class MyAction extends ActionSupport { 
     public final static String DEFAULT_COMMENT = "Default value...";

     private String comment = DEFAULT_COMMENT;
     //... getters setters follow

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well one of the way would be use Javascript function to load Default value on pageload event... Though I am not sure why your tag is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialize the object linked to the field in the previous action method.

In your java File:

```
X object = new X() ;
object.setDesc("");
request.setAttribute("theFormObject",object);
```

In your JSP:

```
<s:textarea name="theFormObject" property="desc" ... />
```